# What is the best way to store and retrieve data from database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database

Lets say If I am storing student information in database.

I want to store student name and each student's ID,age and email. so is it a good idea to go like:

```
INSERT INTO student table ( 
    (studentName, age, email) VALUES
    ('John', 25, 'john@example.com')
)
```

or should i use key value combo ? my main concern is when another student with same name is added and when i retrieve data using student name then ids,age etc get mixed up with another name.

Comment: Where is the student ID that you mentioned? Each row would need something unique, be it a external student ID or just a counting number from a sequence.

Comment: Storing age never seems a good idea to me(John won't be 25 next year). You might consider allocating a student id (not an auto_increment column) since everything else about the student can change (even the name if mispelled).

Comment: _Small Note_ Dont store `age` instead store DateOfBirth. You can calc an age from a DOB but within a year an `age` will be wrong

Comment: above is just rough code i haven't write code yet but I am wondering is it good idea to store this way rather than storing array string like "id:5, age:21,email:john@example.com" in same row? especially when i have to retrieve data not by using primary id but student name

Comment: why don't you use JPA?

Comment: If you have been tasked to create a relational database then you definetly should not store array strings..

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing data in a string array like 'id:5, age:21,email:john@example.com', but if you're going to do that, don't bother with a relational database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have too many parentheses in your syntax.  It should look like this:

```
INSERT INTO student (studentName, age, email)
    VALUES ('John', 25, 'john@example.com');
```

Second, each row in your table should have a unique id, so the table should look like:

```
CREATE TABLE student (
    studentID int auto_increment primary key,
    . . . 
);
```

If other columns are unique -- such as the email -- then use a `unique` constraint or index.

And finally, I have no idea what you mean by getting "mixed up".  Databases store data in rows, which are pretty much defined when you insert the data into one.  The data is retrieved together, as a single row.

Comment: it has unique id and its working fine, but I am wondering is it good idea to store this way rather than storing array string like "id:5, age:21,email:john@example.com" in same row?

Comment: @YugraajSandhu . . . I really don't understand what you could possibly mean.  Storing the values in separate columns with the appropriate type for each column seems like the cleanest and most unambiguous way to store the data.  I can't even figure out where your confusion could be coming from.

Comment: Good answer. FYI, the standard SQL way to define autoincrementing sequence number is `GENERATED AS IDENTITY`, now supported in Postgres and elsewhere. See [this explanation](https://www.2ndquadrant.com/en/blog/postgresql-10-identity-columns/). I don’t know if MySQL has yet implemented this syntax.